# What is better practice for accessing laravel request variables

Tags: laravel

What is better practice for accessing request values in laravel.

For example I have method `update()` in laravel controller.
I want to get values from request, which is better way:

```
method(Request $request) { 
     $request->inputName;
}
```

or

```
method() { 
    request('inputName'); 
}
```

Is it better to create request instance as method attribute or to use Laravel helper method `request()`.

Thanks

Comment: It's up to you. You can use both if you want to.

Answer (score 2):

Both are the same, the first approach might be better in case you create a custom form request where you do the validation of the form. Other than that both provide the same thing.

Comment: That's the answer for my question. Thanks!!

Comment: @Denis2310 consider accepting the answer then, it will help someone else looking for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Controller`

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function update(Request $request)
{
   $name = $request->input('name');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is best way to use

```
method(Request $request) { 
   $request->inputName; 
}
```

Even laravel documentation suggest this.

Answer (score 0):

laravel provides you with methods to get values from the request

now I have request variable is `$request`, it is instance of Request

The better practice for accessing laravel request variables:

If `GET` method, you should use `$request->get('variable_name')`

If `POST` method, you should use `$request->input('variable_name')`

if you want check request has variable you can use `$request->has('variable_name')`

Good luck